# Прокси парсер с использованием curl /Proxy parser using cURL php

Tags: php, curl

Всем привет!Не могу никак реализовать данное задание,уже несколько дней втыкаю и не могу понять что нужно сделать,завис я конкретно на этом пункте(

[
1. Распарсите страницу: http://team24.online/proxy используя CURL
2. Проанализируйте результат, постройте цикл очереди CURL запросов, с участием не меньше 10 портов
3. Запустите цикл c очередью, соберите результат, при достижении количества 100 прокси, цикл - прерывается.
]

Извиняюсь может за глупый вопрос,но я понятия не имею как это реализовать(

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что адресовать его надо тому, кто давал задание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

или лучше примерно так:

```
<?

function pars($url){
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // возвращает веб-страницу
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");        // обрабатывает все кодировки
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);         // таймаут ответа
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);       // останавливаться после 10-ого редиректа

    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    preg_match_all( "/<tr[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/tr>/", $content, $m );

    unset( $m[1][0] );
    $arr = array_values( $m[1] );

    $c = 0;
    $out = array();
    foreach( $arr as $k=>$v ){
        if( $c < 100 ){ //будет перебирать до максимум 100
            $v = explode(" ", trim( strip_tags($v) ) );
            $v = array_filter($v, function($el) {
                return !empty($el);
            });
            $v = array_values( $v );

            $_v['ip'] = trim( $v[0] );
            $_v['port'] = $v[1];

            $out[] = $_v;            
        } else {
            break;
        }
        $c++;
    }
    return $out;
}

print_r( pars("http://team24.online/proxy") ); //Производим парсинг сайта, получаем массив всех ипов и портов

?>
```

на выходе получаем:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 151.238.136.190
            [port] => 2518
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 102.208.243.199
            [port] => 2504
        )
..........
```

Comment: Огромное тебе спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

данные добыты, далее уже разбирай как пожелаешь:

```
<?
function pars($url){
    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    preg_match( "/<table[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/table>/i", $content, $m );

    return strip_tags( $m[1] );
}

echo pars("http://team24.online/proxy"); //Производим парсинг сайта
?>
```